# Changing state of input without requiring user to click in/edit text

Tags: javascript

I have a form with an address finder , the user enters an address in the postcode input and then finds an address and chooses their relevant address. This populates 2 input fields in my form, 1st line of address and postcode.

The form has field by field validation and provides feedback to the user.

```
onchange=""
onblur=""
oninput=""
```

I have a function that validates the input. I want this function to occur as soon as the 2 fields are populated, yet each one of these options requires the user to at least click the input field first, or remove a character/enter a character for the function to invoke. What can I do to apply the function as soon as the input field is populated.

Edit: (Script to check and apply change (address is identical))

```
   function BlurFunctionPost() {        
var data = $("#login-form").serialize();        
$.ajax({                
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'postfieldchecker.php',
    data : data,
    beforeSend: function(){ 
    },
    success : function(response){                       
        if(response=="postok"){                                 
        document.getElementById("postcode").style.border = "2px solid green";

        } else {
        document.getElementById("postcode").style.border = "2px solid red";
        document.getElementById("posterror").className = 
        document.getElementById("posterror").className.replace(/\bhiddenclass\b/,'');
        }
    }
});
    return false;
}
```

And this is the in-line HTML:

```
<input class="hiddenclass" id="postcode" name="postcode" type="text" autocomplete="off" style= "border: 2px solid red;" oninput="BlurFunctionPost()>
```

Comment: Can you please show more example of the code?

Comment: @HDallakyan I have added more examples of the code

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery you can use [change listener](https://api.jquery.com/change/). As I understand you are setting the input's value through Javascript, so in my snippet I emulated it with `$(".hiddenclass").val("myValue");`. And to trigger the validation you should call `trigger` when the value was changed. Change listener will also trigger when user types in the field and deselects it.

```js
$(".hiddenclass").change(function() {
  console.log( "Call validation now!" );
})

$(".hiddenclass").val("myValue");
$(".hiddenclass").trigger( "change" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="hiddenclass" id="postcode" name="postcode" type="text" autocomplete="off" style= "border: 2px solid red;">
```